# why does the "overflow" property give the different result?

Tags: css

The title in first div(overflowhidden) is not in the same vertical position with the title in second div(nooverflow).

The jsfiddle link is as below:

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrnz4mff/)

The html is

```
<div class="line">
    <span class="attr">title :</span>
    <span id="overflowhidden" class="content"> this is long content</span>
</div>

<div class="line">
    <span class="attr">title :</span>
    <span id = "nooverflow" class="content"> this is long content</span>
</div>
```

The css is:

```
.line {
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: 1px dashed;
}

.attr {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}

#overflowhidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please include your code *in* the question.

Comment: As far as I can tell they both look the same? http://jsfiddle.net/84fermg6/10/

Comment: @Dejan.S Sorry, I am not familiar with jsfiddle. the link is update
http://jsfiddle.net/Lrnz4mff/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't have `overflow: hidden;` on both. You said in your css that only one with the id of `#overflowhidden` should have it with this line `#overflowhidden {overflow: hidden;}`

if you set it on the `.content` class is works the same for both. You wanted the same result for both right?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrnz4mff/2/)

```
.content {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     left:40px;
     width:100px;
     height: 20px;
     line-height: 20px;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     white-space: nowrap;
     border-radius: 15px;
     border:1px solid greenyellow;
     overflow:hidden; /*you set it on the class for both to have*/
 }
```

Comment: For the div(nooverflow) I have the content the same as the UI design, later I found the content could be two long, so I add the overflow:hidden to limit its width, But I found the title's vertical postion is moved unexpected, What I really want how to add the overflow:hidden without moving the title's vertical position?